# rvest returns wrong results

Tags: r, rvest

For a research project I want to build a database with university information that is available on topuniversities.com. I manage to write some code to extract the information from the specific university pages so that is fine. To loop over database, I need to extract the links to the university pages that are available at the main page. Here I run into problems. For some reason my code does not identify the links although I can find them with the selector gadget and the inspection pane in Chrome. I assume I do not refer to the right nodes but am not able to solve the problem.

This is my code:

```
url_university_list <- "http://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2015/statistics-operational-research#sorting=rank+region=+country=+faculty=+stars=false+search="
url_university_list %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

a is the node identified by the selector gadget. When I run the code it gives some results but not the links to the university pages.
Ideas?

Comment: At the moment there is a "space" in that URL that prevents resolution of the targetted page.

Comment: Looks like this is a regiatration requiring site and that one needs to log in as well.

Comment: Your endeavours are in violation of #4 of the [ToS](http://www.topuniversities.com/user-agreement).

Comment: I corrected the URL. Apparently I added some spaces when copying the code. I read the ToS and agree it does not seem to be allowed to scrape the website so I probably will refrain from using this source of information. Nevertheless, I still do not understand why rvest is not working properly. You do not need to log in to see the links to the university webpages and go to these pages. Moreover, the inspector gadget and inspect in google chrome clearly show that the links are present on the website. Why does rvest then does not pick them up?